# Breakpoint not working on specific classes on Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, breakpoints

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I Tried all possible setting manipulation of xcode, even i cleaned xcode app from my mac and then reinstalled too, but still no luck, **But Breakpoints works on almost all calsses except some** , later on breakpoint navigator  i noticed classes on which breakpoint not working are marked **RED**. I am wondering what is the actual cause ?

[image]
**Update :** After i removed ad added that specific file the red mark are gone, but result is not improved !

Comment: red files are not exists. you are probably renamed/removed or changed location of  this files.

Comment: They are the missing files so breakpoints does not work on them. That is normal.

Comment: @ridvankucuk and IAmDav : they are not missing, those files are not marked red on project navigator also i have tried removing and re adding those files on project .

Answer (score 0):

I see red text color labels so probably you have deleted files.

If your files exist and you dont see any breakpoint stopped in your class simply it's because your project probably crash before arriving in this class or by-pass it. Check who call `DriveCreateAccountVC` in your code and put some breakpoints before this class is called in the code, Im pretty sure you find your mistake.

It's a good attitude use the debug console by printing your flow in your code like this line for example: (you can put in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad`)

```
print("∙ \(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType))")
```

it's a little help but print the class name where are your flow in this moment. You can go also on the debug console and writing for example:

```
po myStringArray.description
po myStringArray.count
```

Another useful thing is to add these two options in your editing settings (it's not in defaults settings) : (line numbers and code folding ribbon)

[image]

Comment: I have placed breakpoint before and after that particular class too. even new changes on that class reflects on app too.

Comment: Sorry i was only trying to highlight, my mistake :(  Apologise !

 see red text color labels so probably you have deleted files. -> files are not deleted, i have tried removing file from project and again added files on project. files do exist.
 I see red text color labels so probably you have deleted files. If your files exist and you dont see any breakpoint stopped in your class simply it's because your project crash before arriving in this class -> project is not crashing, as i can go through that classes to further other controllers

Comment: NP. I try to give to you the common instrument I use to debug my code,if you dont see printing lines in debug console to the viewDidAppear delegate method of your class probably these class arent called from code.

Comment: Yes sir , i am getting print line are working on that class, but the break point is not !

Comment: Can you show me the screenshot where do you exactly put your breakpoint?

Comment: see update above, btw the print("∙ \(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType))") printing on that class .

Comment: Very strange, it's like the project don't call this class, who called it?

Comment: this Xcode is freshly installed so line number and code folding are missing :) any way thanks for your help, i guess this strange problem is bug of xcode or some thing ! LOL

Comment: However I vote to you to make a better question , now it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

A class becomes Red, when it has lost its path(Xcode can't locate the class)
This may happen because you maybe you copied flies from one project to another or something like that:

There are 2 solutions:

Before anything, locate the files in your Finder

Solution 1) Find the files and put them in your project directory.

Solution 2) Click the file in red in your Project Navigator

[image]

Then click on the button (showed in the image link above, to the right of tweetCell.swift)
Once you click it, you will get a chance to locate the file, do it.